# How can I run Kudan toolkit under linux?

Tags: kudan

How can I generate markers and convert models for Kudan AR engine under Linux? There are only binaries of Kudan toolkit for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudan does not currently have a Linux binary for generating the markers. This is something that may be released in the future.

Comment: Ok, and what about command line windows tool? It is mentioned here https://wiki.kudan.eu/Kudan_AR_Toolkit but I can't find it anywhere. Maybe it will work under Wine. I've tried to launch windows binary under Wine but it is very painful to get it working. It requires .Net4.5 etc.
It will be very cool if you share at least a Windows command line tool. Thanks!